# Is it possible to fix the error "Too many tables: MySQL can only use 61 tables in a join" without remodelling the database

Tags: java, mysql, spring

I have a copy of a Spring boot application and it uses a large dataset, on my manager's PC it works as intended with MSSQL but on my PC it does not, so I opted to use MySQL for testing instead when the application starts and I try to log in the console throws an exception that says: `Too many tables: MySQL can only use 61 tables in a join

Shouldn't the table that stores the users, in my case `user_account` be the only table queried when I attempt to find the account with a specific ID, etc.? In the exception, why are so many table columns added to the JOIN? (Keep in mind that this application was not built by me so I'm learning it as I go :D).

This is the `user_account` entity:

```
@jakarta.persistence.Entity
@Getter @Setter @NoArgsConstructor
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
//@Audited
public class UserAccount implements Entity<Integer>, UserDetails {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    private String username;

    //private UserAccountType userAccountType;

    private Integer numOfFailedAttempts =0;

    private boolean accountNonLocked = true;

    private boolean accountEnabled = true;

    private String password;

    @Transient
    private String newPlainTextPassword;

    @Transient
    private String plainTextPassword;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "userAccounts",
            cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
    private Set<UserRole> userRoles = new HashSet<>();

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "personId")
    private Person person;

    private boolean passwordReset;

    private boolean rolesChanged;

    @Transient
    private boolean admin;
    @Transient
    private boolean employee;
    @Transient
    private boolean approval;
    @Transient
    private boolean reviewer;
    @Transient
    private boolean editor;

    @Setter(AccessLevel.NONE)
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "userAccount",
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            orphanRemoval = true)
    private PreviousRoles previousRoles;

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return userRoles;
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return accountNonLocked;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return accountEnabled;
    }

    public void addUserRole(UserRole userRole){
        userRole.addUserAccount(this);
        userRoles.add(userRole);
    }

    public boolean hasRole(UserRole userRole){
        return userRoles.contains(userRole);
    }

    public boolean hasRole(Role role){
        var userRole = new UserRole(role);
        return hasRole(userRole);
    }

    public void setPreviousRoles(PreviousRoles previousRoles) {
        this.previousRoles = previousRoles;
        previousRoles.setUserAccount(this);
    }

    public Set<String> getRolesAsStrings() {
        var rolesAsStrings = new HashSet<String>();

        userRoles.forEach(userRole ->
                rolesAsStrings.add(userRole.toString()));

        return rolesAsStrings;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username.toLowerCase().trim();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        UserAccount that = (UserAccount) o;
        return Objects.equals(id, that.id);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(id);
    }

    public void setTransientRoles(){
        if (hasRole(Role.ADMIN)) admin = true;
        if (hasRole(Role.APPROVAL)) approval = true;
        if (hasRole(Role.REVIEWER)) reviewer = true;
        if (hasRole(Role.EMPLOYEE)) employee = true;
        if (hasRole(Role.EDITOR)) editor = true;
    }
}
```

This is the exception:

```
org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: JDBC exception executing SQL [select p1_0.id,case when p1_1.id is not null then 1 when p1_2.id is not null then 2 when p1_3.id is not null then 3 when p1_4.id is not null then 4 when p1_0.id is not null then 0 end,b1_0.business_type_id,b1_0.cchidentifier,b1_0.enabled,b1_0.name,b1_0.task_id,c1_0.id,b2_0.business_type_id,b2_0.cchidentifier,b2_0.enabled,b2_0.name,b2_0.task_id,c1_1.created_by_id,c1_1.address1,c1_1.address2,c1_1.address3,c1_1.contactid,c1_1.contact_last_modified,c3_0.contact_type_id,c3_0.contact_type,c3_0.contact_entity_type_id,c1_1.country,c1_1.county,c1_1.date_created,c1_1.email,c1_1.fax,c1_1.first_name,c1_1.last_name,c1_1.mailing_name,c1_1.mobile,c1_1.new_message,c1_1.post_code,c1_1.sex,c1_1.tel,c1_1.town,u1_0.id,u1_0.account_enabled,u1_0.account_non_locked,u1_0.num_of_failed_attempts,u1_0.password,u1_0.password_reset,u1_0.person_id,u1_0.roles_changed,u1_0.username,c1_1.zid,c1_0.audit_user_name,c1_0.birth_place,c1_0.cds_code,c1_0.charge_rates_note,c1_0.cost_per_hour,c1_0.date_of_birth,c1_0.employee_code,c1_0.expense_processing_category_id,c1_0.extension,c1_0.f_name_temp,c1_0.gender,c1_0.initial_department_id,c1_0.new_activity_on_assigned_forms,p3_0.id,case when p3_1.id is not null then 1 when p3_2.id is not null then 2 when p3_3.id is not null then 3 when p3_4.id is not null then 4 when p3_0.id is not null then 0 end,p3_0.business_type_id,p3_0.created_by_id,p3_0.address1,p3_0.address2,p3_0.address3,p3_0.contactid,p3_0.contact_last_modified,p3_0.contact_type_id,p3_0.country,p3_0.county,p3_0.date_created,p3_0.email,p3_0.fax,p3_0.first_name,p3_0.last_name,p3_0.mailing_name,p3_0.mobile,p3_0.new_message,p3_0.post_code,p3_0.sex,p3_0.tel,p3_0.town,p3_0.zid,p3_1.affiliate_id,p3_1.id,p3_1.approved_by,p3_1.birth_place,p3_1.business_type_id,p3_1.cdscode,p3_1.cease_trading_date,p3_1.checked_out_by_employee_id,p3_1.checked_out_date,p3_1.contact_closed,p3_1.contact_closed_reason_id,p3_1.contact_num,p3_1.contact_typeid,p3_1.current_mailshot,p3_1.date_of_birth,p3_1.date_of_death,p3_1.department_id,p3_1.draft,p3_1.external_use,p3_1.gdprdelete_in_progress,p3_1.gdprdeletion_date,p3_1.hmrcr40,p3_1.incorporation_date,p3_1.initials,p3_1.lnamefname,p3_1.master_mailshot,p3_1.mname,p3_1.ninumber,p3_1.notes,p3_1.office_id,p3_1.our_ref,p3_1.photo,p3_1.ppsn,p3_1.pref,p3_1.resp_notes,p3_1.restricted_client_team_access,p3_1.row_guid,p3_1.salutation,p3_1.suff,p3_1.utr,p3_2.approved_by,p3_2.id,p3_2.birth_place,p3_2.business_type_id,p3_2.cdscode,p3_2.cease_trading_date,p3_2.checked_out_by_employee_id,p3_2.checked_out_date,p3_2.company_id,p3_2.contact_closed,p3_2.contact_closed_reason_id,p3_2.contact_num,p3_2.date_of_birth,p3_2.date_of_death,p3_2.department_id,p3_2.email,p3_2.external_use,p3_2.gdprdeletion_date,p3_2.hmrcr40,p3_2.incorporation_date,p3_2.initials,p3_2.lnamefname,p3_2.mname,p3_2.ninumber,p3_2.notes,p3_2.office_id,p3_2.our_ref,p3_2.person_id,p3_2.photo,p3_2.ppsn,p3_2.pref,p3_2.resp_notes,p3_2.row_guid,p3_2.salutation,p3_2.suff,p3_2.utr,p3_3.client_id,p3_3.incorporation_date,p3_3.account_status_id,p3_3.approval_emp_id,p3_3.approved_by_id,p3_3.id,p3_3.bacs_ref,p3_3.bank_account_name,p3_3.bank_account_num,p3_3.bank_sort_code,p3_3.business_type_id,p3_3.cli_file_id,p3_3.client_closed_reason_id,p3_3.client_code,p3_3.client_type,p3_3.closed,p3_3.company_registration_no,p3_3.company_tax_reference,p3_3.created_date,p3_3.credit_limit,p3_3.default_contact_assoc_id,p3_3.default_currency,p3_3.default_nominal_id,p3_3.default_recovery_rate,p3_3.department_id_department_id,p3_3.draft,p3_3.email,p3_3.internal,p3_3.kyc_initialised,p3_3.kyc_status,p3_3.last_touch_date,p3_3.last_touch_point_touchpoint_id,p3_3.mobile_contact,p3_3.name,p3_3.new_activity,p3_3.notes,p3_3.office_contact,p3_3.office_id,p3_3.parent_client_id,p3_3.payment_type_id,p3_3.period_end_date,p3_3.person_id,p3_3.reason_won_id,p3_3.restricted_client_team_access,p3_3.row_guid,p3_3.status,p3_3.telephone_number,p3_3.terms_day,p3_4.id,p3_4.audit_user_name,p3_4.birth_place,p3_4.cds_code,p3_4.charge_rates_note,p3_4.cost_per_hour,p3_4.date_of_birth,p3_4.employee_code,p3_4.expense_processing_category_id,p3_4.extension,p3_4.f_name_temp,p3_4.gender,p3_4.initial_department_id,p3_4.new_activity_on_assigned_forms,p3_4.person_id,p3_4.personal_notes,p3_4.pin,p3_4.pref_temp,p3_4.row_guid,p3_4.s_name_temp,p3_4.security_group_id,p3_4.sort_code,p3_4.system_done_id,p3_4.tab_text_length,p3_4.time_processing_category_id,p3_4.time_unit_id,p3_4.user_name,c1_0.personal_notes,c1_0.pin,c1_0.pref_temp,c1_0.row_guid,c1_0.s_name_temp,c1_0.security_group_id,c1_0.sort_code,c1_0.system_done_id,c1_0.tab_text_length,c1_0.time_processing_category_id,c1_0.time_unit_id,c1_0.user_name,p1_0.address1,p1_0.address2,p1_0.address3,p1_0.contactid,p1_0.contact_last_modified,c6_0.contact_type_id,c6_0.contact_type,c6_0.contact_entity_type_id,p1_0.country,p1_0.county,p1_0.date_created,p1_0.email,p1_0.fax,p1_0.first_name,p1_0.last_name,p1_0.mailing_name,p1_0.mobile,p1_0.new_message,p1_0.post_code,p1_0.sex,p1_0.tel,p1_0.town,u2_0.id,u2_0.account_enabled,u2_0.account_non_locked,u2_0.num_of_failed_attempts,u2_0.password,u2_0.password_reset,p7_0.id,u2_0.roles_changed,u2_0.username,p1_0.zid,p1_1.affiliate_id,p1_1.id,p1_1.approved_by,p1_1.birth_place,p1_1.business_type_id,p1_1.cdscode,p1_1.cease_trading_date,p1_1.checked_out_by_employee_id,p1_1.checked_out_date,p1_1.contact_closed,p1_1.contact_closed_reason_id,p1_1.contact_num,p1_1.contact_typeid,p1_1.current_mailshot,p1_1.date_of_birth,p1_1.date_of_death,p1_1.department_id,p1_1.draft,p1_1.external_use,p1_1.gdprdelete_in_progress,p1_1.gdprdeletion_date,p1_1.hmrcr40,p1_1.incorporation_date,p1_1.initials,p1_1.lnamefname,p1_1.master_mailshot,p1_1.mname,p1_1.ninumber,p1_1.notes,p1_1.office_id,p1_1.our_ref,p1_1.photo,p1_1.ppsn,p1_1.pref,p1_1.resp_notes,p1_1.restricted_client_team_access,p1_1.row_guid,p1_1.salutation,p1_1.suff,p1_1.utr,p1_2.approved_by,p1_2.id,p1_2.birth_place,p1_2.business_type_id,p1_2.cdscode,p1_2.cease_trading_date,p1_2.checked_out_by_employee_id,p1_2.checked_out_date,p1_2.company_id,p1_2.contact_closed,p1_2.contact_closed_reason_id,p1_2.contact_num,p1_2.date_of_birth,p1_2.date_of_death,p1_2.department_id,p1_2.email,p1_2.external_use,p1_2.gdprdeletion_date,p1_2.hmrcr40,p1_2.incorporation_date,p1_2.initials,p1_2.lnamefname,p1_2.mname,p1_2.ninumber,p1_2.notes,p1_2.office_id,p1_2.our_ref,p8_0.id,case when p8_1.id is not null then 1 when p8_2.id is not null then 2 when p8_3.id is not null then 3 when p8_4.id is not null then 4 when p8_0.id is not null then 0 end,b5_0.business_type_id,b5_0.cchidentifier,b5_0.enabled,b5_0.name,b5_0.task_id,c7_0.id,c7_1.business_type_id,c7_1.created_by_id,c7_1.address1,c7_1.address2,c7_1.address3,c7_1.contactid,c7_1.contact_last_modified,c7_1.contact_type_id,c7_1.country,c7_1.county,c7_1.date_created,c7_1.email,c7_1.fax,c7_1.first_name,c7_1.last_name,c7_1.mailing_name,c7_1.mobile,c7_1.new_message,c7_1.post_code,c7_1.sex,c7_1.tel,c7_1.town,c7_1.id,c7_1.zid,c7_0.audit_user_name,c7_0.birth_place,c7_0.cds_code,c7_0.charge_rates_note,c7_0.cost_per_hour,c7_0.date_of_birth,c7_0.employee_code,c7_0.expense_processing_category_id,c7_0.extension,c7_0.f_name_temp,c7_0.gender,c7_0.initial_department_id,c7_0.new_activity_on_assigned_forms,c7_0.person_id,c7_0.personal_notes,c7_0.pin,c7_0.pref_temp,c7_0.row_guid,c7_0.s_name_temp,c7_0.security_group_id,c7_0.sort_code,c7_0.system_done_id,c7_0.tab_text_length,c7_0.time_processing_category_id,c7_0.time_unit_id,c7_0.user_name,p8_0.address1,p8_0.address2,p8_0.address3,p8_0.contactid,p8_0.contact_last_modified,c10_0.contact_type_id,c10_0.contact_type,c10_0.contact_entity_type_id,p8_0.country,p8_0.county,p8_0.date_created,p8_0.email,p8_0.fax,p8_0.first_name,p8_0.last_name,p8_0.mailing_name,p8_0.mobile,p8_0.new_message,p8_0.post_code,p8_0.sex,p8_0.tel,p8_0.town,u3_0.id,u3_0.account_enabled,u3_0.account_non_locked,u3_0.num_of_failed_attempts,u3_0.password,u3_0.password_reset,u3_0.roles_changed,u3_0.username,p8_0.zid,p8_1.affiliate_id,p8_1.id,p8_1.approved_by,p8_1.birth_place,p8_1.business_type_id,p8_1.cdscode,p8_1.cease_trading_date,p8_1.checked_out_by_employee_id,p8_1.checked_out_date,p8_1.contact_closed,p8_1.contact_closed_reason_id,p8_1.contact_num,p8_1.contact_typeid,p8_1.current_mailshot,p8_1.date_of_birth,p8_1.date_of_death,p8_1.department_id,p8_1.draft,p8_1.external_use,p8_1.gdprdelete_in_progress,p8_1.gdprdeletion_date,p8_1.hmrcr40,p8_1.incorporation_date,p8_1.initials,p8_1.lnamefname,p8_1.master_mailshot,p8_1.mname,p8_1.ninumber,p8_1.notes,p8_1.office_id,p8_1.our_ref,p8_1.photo,p8_1.ppsn,p8_1.pref,p8_1.resp_notes,p8_1.restricted_client_team_access,p8_1.row_guid,p8_1.salutation,p8_1.suff,p8_1.utr,p8_2.approved_by,p8_2.id,p8_2.birth_place,p8_2.business_type_id,p8_2.cdscode,p8_2.cease_trading_date,p8_2.checked_out_by_employee_id,p8_2.checked_out_date,p8_2.company_id,p8_2.contact_closed,p8_2.contact_closed_reason_id,p8_2.contact_num,p8_2.date_of_birth,p8_2.date_of_death,p8_2.department_id,p8_2.email,p8_2.external_use,p8_2.gdprdeletion_date,p8_2.hmrcr40,p8_2.incorporation_date,p8_2.initials,p8_2.lnamefname,p8_2.mname,p8_2.ninumber,p8_2.notes,p8_2.office_id,p8_2.our_ref,p8_2.person_id,p8_2.photo,p8_2.ppsn,p8_2.pref,p8_2.resp_notes,p8_2.row_guid,p8_2.salutation,p8_2.suff,p8_2.utr,p8_3.client_id,p8_3.incorporation_date,a3_0.account_status_id,a3_0.account_status_desc,a3_0.account_status_typeid,p8_3.approval_emp_id,a4_0.id,a4_1.business_type_id,a4_1.created_by_id,a4_1.address1,a4_1.address2,a4_1.address3,a4_1.contactid,a4_1.contact_last_modified,a4_1.contact_type_id,a4_1.country,a4_1.county,a4_1.date_created,a4_1.email,a4_1.fax,a4_1.first_name,a4_1.last_name,a4_1.mailing_name,a4_1.mobile,a4_1.new_message,a4_1.post_code,a4_1.sex,a4_1.tel,a4_1.town,a4_1.id,a4_1.zid,a4_0.audit_user_name,a4_0.birth_place,a4_0.cds_code,a4_0.charge_rates_note,a4_0.cost_per_hour,a4_0.date_of_birth,a4_0.employee_code,a4_0.expense_processing_category_id,a4_0.extension,a4_0.f_name_temp,a4_0.gender,a4_0.initial_department_id,a4_0.new_activity_on_assigned_forms,a4_0.person_id,a4_0.personal_notes,a4_0.pin,a4_0.pref_temp,a4_0.row_guid,a4_0.s_name_temp,a4_0.security_group_id,a4_0.sort_code,a4_0.system_done_id,a4_0.tab_text_length,a
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Too many tables; MySQL can only use 61 tables in a join
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:130) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:916) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ClientPreparedStatement.java:972) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:52) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.jdbc.internal.DeferredResultSetAccess.executeQuery(DeferredResultSetAccess.java:239) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.6.Final.jar:6.2.6.Final]
    ... 135 common frames omitted
```

The maximum heap memory is set to 4096m and the minimum heap memory is set to 3072m [image: Java heap], when using MSSQL the used heap memory reaches the maximum and throws the following exception:

```
Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "JFR Periodic Tasks"
Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "RMI TCP Connection(idle)"
Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "JMX server connection timeout 72"
Exception in thread "mysql-cj-abandoned-connection-cleanup" Exception in thread "RMI TCP Connection(idle)" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

**I have no issues running this application with MSSQL on spring-boot version 2.7, Java 11, and spring-security 5**

Comment: Why you put photo of display with code here ? Can you paste your error code ?

Comment: @Kafarson the exception is too long

Comment: This is a great example of why it's important to test with the same brand and version of database you will eventually deploy to. MySQL and Microsoft SQL Server are different products. If you try to use one as the other, you're bound to encounter differences in features, errors, performance, etc.

Comment: This is a documented limitation. so no it can't be 'fixed' https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html#:~:text=The%20maximum%20number%20of%20tables,a%20single%20join%20is%2061.

Comment: @BillKarwin While you are correct that different databases behave differently, in this case, the problem is likely the code (joining 61 tables is seldom the correct way of doing things).

Comment: I'm guessing this is some kind of automatic behavior of Spring, to generate queries that eagerly join to related tables, and then join to subsequently related tables, and so on until the whole set of related tables are joined in every query. But the OP's question doesn't show any other entity class, or any SQL query.

Comment: “it's too long to past[e] into StackOverflow” …Then paste the first ten lines of it.  I’m not sure the UserAccount entity class has anything to do with this.

Comment: @VGR I pasted the first ten lines of the exception.

Comment: Thanks, that helps.  We don’t need to see the rest of the SQL statement, but we do need the lines which come after it.  Each such line starts with either `at` or `Caused by:`.  This is the stack trace, and it tells us, and you, where the problem occurred.

Comment: @VGR sorry again, I just added the `caused by: `

Comment: The simple answer to your question is: Yes it is possible: Review and re-design the relationship of your entities. Make sure to make the correct usage of the `FetchType` when creating the relationships. Based on the entity you shared here I would say that the problem is specifically the manyToMany one which is eagerly fetching everything associated with roles and the previous roles for each user.